# Exchange ERC20 token with other ERC20 token

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, ethereumjs

I have 2 ERC20 tokens. The contract are designed as standard ERC20. Here are the 2 tokens to take as an example -

```
AUDC --> Contract Address: (0xContractAUDC)
         Wallet Address:   (0xWalletAUDC)
DAI  --> Contract Address: (0xContractDAI)
         Wallet Address:   (0xWalletDAI)
```

I want to transfer some DAI from wallet `0xWalletDAI` to `0xWalletAUDC` to receive converted AUDC in return (I have private keys of both the wallets).

Looking for some help to know how this can be implemented. I would try to be helpful with more information if needed.

I am using `ethers.js v4.0` to interact with blockchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add `"web3": "1.2.1"` to your `package.json` file and run `npm install` (or simply run `npm install web3`).

Second, try the following node script:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

async function run() {
    const abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"standard","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_symbol","type":"string"},{"name":"_decimals","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];
    const web3 = new Web3(YOUR_ETHEREUM_NODE_URL);
    const contractDAI = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0xContractDAI");
    const contractAUDC = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0xContractAUDC");
    const receipt1 = await send(web3, contractDAI.methods.transfer("0xWalletAUDC", "DesiredAmountOfDAI"), "0xWalletDAIPrivateKey"));
    const receipt2 = await send(web3, contractAUDC.methods.transfer("0xWalletDAI", "DesiredAmountOfAUDC"), "0xWalletAUDCPrivateKey"));
    console.log(receipt1);
    console.log(receipt2);
}

async function send(web3, transaction, privateKey, value = 0, retry = true) {
    while (this.gasPrice == undefined) {
        const nodeGasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        process.stdout.write(`Enter gas-price or leave empty to use ${nodeGasPrice}: `);
        const userGasPrice = await scan();
        if (/^\d+$/.test(userGasPrice))
            this.gasPrice = userGasPrice;
        else if (userGasPrice == "")
            this.gasPrice = nodeGasPrice;
        else
            console.log("Illegal gas-price");
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            const options = {
                value   : value,
                to      : transaction._parent._address,
                data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
                gas     : (await web3.eth.getBlock("latest")).gasLimit,
                gasPrice: this.gasPrice
            };
            const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey);
            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
            return receipt;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            if (retry) {
                while (true) {
                    process.stdout.write("Enter transaction-hash or leave empty to retry: ");
                    const hash = await scan();
                    if (/^0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{64})$/.test(hash)) {
                        const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
                        if (receipt)
                            return receipt;
                        console.log("Invalid transaction-hash");
                    }
                    else if (hash) {
                        console.log("Illegal transaction-hash");
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                return {};
            }
        }
    }
}

async function scan() {
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            process.stdin.pause();
            resolve(data.toString().trim());
        });
    });
}

run();
```

You'll need to set `YOUR_ETHEREUM_NODE_URL` of course.

Tested with node v10.16.0.

Comment: thanks alot.. This helped me to understand the process. Could you help me know, how this can be implemented using ether.js instead of web3?

Comment: @DIGVJSS: What's your motivation of preferring one over the other?

Comment: I already have existing platform built over ether.js

Comment: So add `web3` to it. They're not contradicting each other.

Comment: I am trying to avoid redundant implementations. I already have the configuration classes created using ether.js. I am not looking to do the same thing for web3. I will keep checking if the above solution could be implemented using ether.js. Thanks!

Comment: OK. Nevertheless, I'm pretty sure that web3.js has everything that ether.js has to offer (but not vice-versa).

Comment: I implemented this, but the signer account needs ethers to sign the transaction. Is this correct?

Comment: @DIGVJSS: Yes It needs at least `value + gas * gasPrice`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using ether.js library -

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();

// WALLETS
const DAIUserWalletObj = new ethers.Wallet(DAIUserPrivateKey, provider);
const AUDCWalletObj = new ethers.Wallet(AUDCPrivateKey, provider);

//CONTRACTS
const contractDAI = new ethers.Contract(DAIContractAddress, DAIContractABI, provider);
constractDAI = contractDAI.connect(DAIUserWalletObj);
const contractAUDC = new ethers.Contract(AUDCContractAddress, AUDCContractABI, provider);
contractAUDC = contractAUDC.connect(AUDCWalletObj);

let overRide = { gasLimit: 7500000 }
let numDAITokens = 20;  // Just for example
let numOfAUDCTokens = 40; // Just for example
const receipt1 = await contractDAI.transfer(AUDCContractAddress, numDAITokens, overRide);
const receipt2 = await contractAUDC.transfer(DAIUserWalletAddress, numOfAUDCTokens, overRide);
console.log(receipt1);
console.log(receipt2);
```